# Example free test site for https SOAP

Tags: php, soap, https, certificate

Is there an https free test site available that I can use to test calling https SOAP webservices (using php5 soapClient object by the way) so that I can see what the impact is of having or not having correctly installed the certificate?

So far, I tried calling SOAP webservices like the ones mentioned in https://uk.ewaypayments.com/hotpotato/soap.asmx?WSDL or https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/test/manageRebill_test.asmx?WSDL, but I guess I am missing something or that certificates are installed automatically already in the browsers I used (IE9 and Chrome), because I did not have to do any certificate stuff.

Comment: Most web services that use WSDL have URLs specifically for testing. Check with the web service host.

Comment: True and I thought that eway's manageRebill_test would serve me well. But as I said, I did not have to install any certificate myself so I wonder whether I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

This is a collection of different SOAP APIs that are completley public and do not require any authentication, making it easier for consumers to play with and understand what APIs are all about by seeing the many different ways in which APIs can be used.

[Public SOAP APIs - Postman](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8854915/Szf26WHn#4ba276a7-b12c-4943-ae23-c6031cc48248)

Remember, you can get a WSDL from any ASMX endpoint by adding `?wsdl` to the url.

For example: https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?wsdl